# ebs durability clarification

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I am confused as to the durability of the EBS volumes on AWS.

> As an example, volumes that operate with 20 GB or less of modified data since their most recent Amazon EBS snapshot can expect an annual failure rate (AFR) of between 0.1% – 0.5%, where failure refers to a complete loss of the volume. This compares with commodity hard disks that will typically fail with an AFR of around 4%, making EBS volumes 10 times more reliable than typical commodity disk drives.
>
> Because Amazon EBS servers are replicated within a single Availability Zone, mirroring data across multiple Amazon EBS volumes in the same Availability Zone will not significantly improve volume durability.

Does this mean that the 1/200-1/1000 probability of failure is **before** the automatic replication or after?

Answer (score 1):

> As an example, volumes that operate with 20 GB or less of modified data since their most recent Amazon EBS snapshot can expect an annual failure rate (AFR) of between 0.1% – 0.5%, where failure refers to a complete loss of the volume.

The quoted AFR refers to the end-to-end experience of using an EBS volume. EBS replication is completely transparent to you, and you won't even know when one of the replicas fails and is automatically replaced.